# Why this weird compatibility of bool and pointers in C++?

Tags: c++, pointers, overloading

Not only is this valid and doesn't give any warnings even with -Wall:

```
void* p = false;  // actually 'true' doesn't work here
bool b = "Hello, Boolean!";
```

but also this compatibility rule permits selecting an overloaded function/operator for a wrong type. Let's say you overloaded your `operator <<` for all fundamental types and you forgot to overload the void pointer, then the compiler may select the version that takes `bool`, or the other way around.

So what is it that makes this compatibility rule more important than the weird (and highly undesirable) side effects with overloaded functions?

(Edit: removed all references to C, they were wrong: the conversion rules are basically the same in C.)

Comment: The C language before C99 doesn't have a built-in native `bool` type - it's sometimes emulated via `#define`. Saying that "C can handle this correctly" doesn't make much sense.

Comment: @In silico: In C, there is a built-in `_Bool` type.

Comment: @dreamlax: Right. I forgot to mention that the C language prior to C99 didn't have it. However, the OP did use `bool` instead of `_Bool`, so I assumed that the OP used an emulated `bool`.

Comment: @In silico: C99 defines `bool`, `true`, and `false` as well, if you include the `stdbool.h` header.

Comment: Not valid in c++. At the very least, quite questionable.

Comment: "...and doesn't give any warnings even with -Wall" - `-Wconversion` should do the trick. On Microsoft platforms, /W3 and above should produce the warnings.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What do you mean by "C can handle this correctly"?  C doesn't permit function overloading, so you are guaranteed to have the bool <-> pointer conversion you're complaining about.

Are you asking why this conversion exists?

The first is not actually a conversion bool -> pointer, but is recognizing that the literal `false` means 0, which is a valid pointer value.  That's why it doesn't work with `true`, and it doesn't work with a `bool` variable.

The second is because it's nice to be able to write:

```
if (p)
```

instead of

```
if (p != 0)
```

to check if a pointer holds a null pointer value.

EDIT: Rules from the standard influencing `T* p = false;`:

> A null pointer constant is an integral constant expression prvalue of integer type that evaluates to zero

and

> Types bool, char, char16_t, char32_t, wchar_t, and the signed and unsigned integer types are collectively called integral types. A synonym for integral type is integer type.

and

> The Boolean literals are the keywords false and true. Such literals are prvalues and have type bool.

Comment: I don't believe this compatibility exists just because `if (p)` looks nice (which I agree, it does). So if false and zero play nicely with pointers, it doesn't explain why you can't assign pointers to ints but you can assign them to bool variables.

Comment: Well, the pointer -> bool conversion has a couple other common manifestations... `do { } while (p = p->next);` or `p && p->dostuff();`  And you can assign pointers to other integral types, it just isn't implicit.

Comment: @Mojuba, there is a pointer-to-bool conversion, and there is a bool-to-int conversion. But the compiler won't do two implicit conversions together, so you don't get a pointer-to-int conversion. Make the first conversion explicit, and you're OK: `int x = (bool)ptr;`

Comment: @Rob Kennedy: that probably explains it best. But I still can't believe they did it just for the sake of `if (p)`

Comment: @mojuba: Considering C++ is supposed to be able to compile code that is C, that's *exactly* why it is done that way. If it was not done that way, than a very very large class of C programs would not compile as C++.

Comment: In the same way, there is a zero to pointer conversion (called null pointer conversion), and bool to other-integrals conversion (converting false to zero, called integer promotion/conversion). The compiler should not be allowed to allow assigning a const false bool to a pointer, I think, because it requires two conversions. Value false != value zero. But apparently all compilers accept it.

Comment: @Johannes: I'm pretty sure that behavior is required by the standard, see edit.  It requires no conversions.

Comment: @Ben the things you quoted do not say that "false" is zero. "false" is a boolean value, out of which do only exist 2 (the other being "true"). Unless the Standard states it explicitly, I can't see why these two boolean values should be regarded as being zero and one (which 0 and 1 naturally are, as opposed to false and true).

Comment: @Johannes: But all that's necessary is that it evaluates to zero. And integral promotion says it does: <quote>A prvalue of type bool can be converted to a prvalue of type int, with false becoming zero and true
becoming one.</quote>

Comment: @Johannes:  Any integral constant expression that evaluates to `0` can be implicitly converted to a null pointer constant; `false` is a valid integral constant expression and it evaluates to `0`.

Comment: @Ben C++03 does not really define what "evaluates" means. This argument requires, unless I'm missing something, that "x evaluates to y" means "x can somehow be converted to y". But then we should also be allowed to do `int *p = UCHAR_MAX + 1;`, because after all `UCHAR_MAX + 1` converted to `unsigned char` is zero.